# Showing that closed sets in R+ are closed in R

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove that a closed set in $\mathbb{R}_+$ is also closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

I've tried a few avenues of reasoning but am quite stuck. If anyone could give me a little hint it would be greatly appreciated. I'm doing some pre-study of the mathematical appendix of a graduate level microeconomics course, and got a bit stuck on the "a bit of topology" section.

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I should've included that as to not waste people's time.

I initially tried proving that the union of $\mathbb{R}_+\setminus S$ and $\mathbb{R}_{--}$ was open. But then I ran into the problem that $\mathbb{R}_+\setminus S$ was open in $\mathbb{R}_+$ but closed in $\mathbb{R}$. So that didn't work.

Will reply back shortly with one other thing I'm trying.

Comment: Don't see how that can be as $(0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb R_+$ but is not closed in $\mathbb R$.  Are you using $\mathbb R_+$ differently than I am?

Comment: Is $\mathbb R_+$ the set of positive real numbers *with zero* or *without zero*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to ensure we are talking about the same thing: let $\mathbb{R}^+ := \mathbb{R}\cap\{x| x> 0\}$

With this, your statement is not true, the example from fleablood in the comments $(0,1]$ is a counterexample.

The converse statement is true, if $A$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, then $A\cap \mathbb{R}^+$ is closed in  $\mathbb{R}^+$.

What is also true is that if $B\subset  \mathbb{R}^+$ is closed then there exists a closed set $B^\prime \subset  \mathbb{R}$ such that $B = B^\prime\cap \mathbb{R}$. That you can take as a definition of a set being closed  in $\mathbb{R}^+ $.

(If you define $\mathbb{R}^+ := \mathbb{R}\cap\{x| x\ge 0\}$ then your statement is correct. This is true because in this case, the set $\mathbb{R}^+ $ itself is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. If then $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^+ $ there exists a closed set $A^\prime \subset \mathbb{R} $ such that $A= \mathbb{R}^+ \cap A^\prime$, and then $A$ is closed *in* $\mathbb{R} $ as finite intersection of closed sets ).

Comment: Right, my economics textbook defines $\mathbb{R}_+:=\mathbb{R}\cap\{x|x≥0\}$.

Thanks very much for your answer. I'm going to ponder this some more on my own.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Generally, if $X$ is a topological space, $F\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$ and $A\subseteq F$ is closed in $F$ then $A$ is closed in $X$. This is because (by definition) $A$ can be written as $F\cap A'$ for some closed subset $A'\subseteq X$.

On the other hand assume that arbitrary $F\subseteq X$ is given. If we assume that every subset that is closed in $F$ is also closed in $X$, then in particular $F$ is closed in $F$, and so it has to be closed in $X$. Which gives us the following description:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $F\subseteq X$. Then every closed subset of $F$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $F$ is closed in $X$.

So your question really depends only on what $\mathbb{R}^+$ is. If $\mathbb{R}^+=(0,\infty)$ which is a typical definition, then it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and thus it does not have the property you want. On the other hand if $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,\infty)$, which is probably a reasonable definition, then it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and indeed it has the property.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you very much.